# How to make jquery event functions synchronous?

Tags: jquery, async-await

I want get values from `<select>` and `<input>` tags for further processing but as JS is async in nature so it's not waiting for values to be retrieved and goes to next step without waiting. Here is my code:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $("select.form-control").change(function(){
        invoiceType=$(this).children("option:selected").val();
    });

    $("input").blur(function(){
        invoiceNumber=$(this).val();
    });

    if(invoiceNumber && invoiceType){ // here I am getting undefined
      //logic
    }
}
```

**Thing I tried:**

1) Async/await

2) Jquery.when().then()
But no luck. Thanks for help.

Comment: Any you stuck on something, the answers provided here sufficiently solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I didn't go this way. What I did is:
`if($("input").val() && $("select.form-control").children("option:selected").val()){}`
and removed the event change for both input fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it in a very simple way. Just call a function in both the event handlers and do your logic if both the variables are defined.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  let invoiceType, invoiceNumber;
  $("select.form-control").change(function() {
    invoiceType = $(this)
      .children("option:selected")
      .val();
    doSomething();
  });

  $("input").blur(function() {
    invoiceNumber = $(this).val();
    doSomething();
  });

  function doSomething() {
    if (invoiceNumber && invoiceType) {
      //logic
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help but It'll trigger my logic as soon as both options reached to true even without clicking button. I want these two values  to be true but to trigger logic on button click.

Comment: Then why are you nesting the event handler registration inside the button click? You can register the event handlers outside the `click` and just do the `doSomething` function inside.

Comment: because I wanted to trigger events for input fields when the button clicked. Is it wrong approach?

Comment: I'm confused. If you want to just access the details of your inputs on button click, then why do you need event handlers at all? You can just get the current value via the required selectors right?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was doing wrong here. Now I just picked up the value of inputs

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful registering those events in the `click` handler. Things could get messy quickly if you don't deregister them.

You'll need some state to track things, so I created `eventFlags`:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let select = document.querySelector('select');
let input = document.querySelector('input');

let eventFlags = {
  clicked: false,
  changed: false,
  blurred: false
};

button.onclick = function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  eventFlags.clicked = true;
  return false;
};

select.onchange = function(event) {
  console.log('changed');
  eventFlags.changed = event.target.value;
  doCheck();
};

input.onblur = function(event) {
  console.log('blurred');
  eventFlags.blurred = event.target.value;
  doCheck();
};

function doCheck() {
  if (eventFlags.clicked &&
    eventFlags.changed &&
    eventFlags.blurred) {
    alert(`ready: ${eventFlags.changed} ${eventFlags.blurred}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>button</td>
      <td>
        <button>click</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>select</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="a">A</option>
          <option value="b">B</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>input</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</form>
```